# Помогите с Hibernate не создаются таблицы

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Помогите hibernate не создает таблицы. Возможно нарушен мапинг!

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> уже настроил и включил.
```

---

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "team", schema = "bank1")
public class Team implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5924361831551833717L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "team_id")
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Integer rating;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Credit> credits;
```

---

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "credit",schema = "bank1")
public class Credit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5527566248002296042L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "credit_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", nullable = false)
    private Team teamId;
}
```

---

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.sprhib")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_hbm2ddl_auto = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_hbm2ddl_auto,env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_hbm2ddl_auto));
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

а вот что валит...

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
  mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: 
  com.sprhib.model.Credit.team in com.sprhib.model.Team.credits
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Credit> credits;
```

у вас нет свойства `team` в классе Credit. Есть `teamId`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id", nullable = false)
private Team teamId;
```

Comment: только что поставил как вы написали. Таблицы не создаются.

Comment: @Verlamov ну вам же выдает конкретную ошибку в лог. чините по ошибкам, пока не начнет создаваться.